# PHP each or foreach to print data

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, each

first, thanks for your attention!

After run a query, I have a result like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|post_id|   meta_key   |  meta_value |
--------------------------------------
|   1   |     name     |    jeff     |
--------------------------------------
|   1   |     email    |  x@mail.com |
--------------------------------------
|   1   |     color    |     blue    |
--------------------------------------
|   2   |     name     |    mary     |
--------------------------------------
|   2   |     email    |  y@mail.com |
--------------------------------------
|   2   |     color    |     pink    |
--------------------------------------
```

The Array

```
array(6) 
{ 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#448 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "1" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(4) "name" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(4) "jeff" 
        } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#449 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "1" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(4) "email" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(10) "x@mail.com" 
        } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#450 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "1" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(5) "color" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(4) "blue" 
        } 
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#448 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "2" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(4) "name" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(4) "mary" 
        } 
    [4]=> object(stdClass)#449 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "2" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(4) "email" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(10) "y@mail.com" 
        } 
    [5]=> object(stdClass)#450 (3) 
        { 
            ["post_id"]     => string(1) "2" 
            ["meta_key"]    => string(5) "color" 
            ["meta_value"]  => string(4) "pink" 
        }
```

}

Well, I have 1 ID for 3 labels and 3 values. Using PHP, I need to know how to do a foreach or each to print this data like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|post_id|    name      |    email    |   color    |
---------------------------------------------------
|   1   |    jeff      |  x@mail.com |   blue     |
---------------------------------------------------
|   2   |    mary      |  y@mail.com |   pink     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now, with help of Kostas Mitsarakis, I have one code, but this code, in my case, is returning NULL values.

The code:

```
global $wpdb;

$meta_value = interested_get_meta( 'interested_email' );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
       'SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE post_id 
        IN (    SELECT post_id 
                FROM wp_postmeta 
                WHERE meta_value = "'.$meta_value.'"
            )', OBJECT
);

$data = array();
$result = array($results);

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['post_id'], $data)) {
        $data[$value['post_id']]['post_id'] = $value['post_id'];
    }
    if ($value['meta_key'] != 'post_id') {
        $data[$value['post_id']][$value['meta_key']] =     $value['meta_value'];
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

The returns of var_dump:

```
array(1) { [""]=> array(2) { ["post_id"]=> NULL [""]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: Can you show the query? I think that it would be better if you had the rights results using SQL.

Comment: do a `GROUP BY id` and an ORDER BY, then set it inside an HTML formatted table.

Comment: you can run for and modulo by 3 but better solution would be to modify query

Comment: Comment out // $data = array(); And then instead of: $results = $wpdb->get_results... WRITE: $data = $wpdb->get_results... because you use $data which in this case is empty.

Comment: Kostas, after do the suggested changes, I got the same array into a new no major changes. Maybe I'm not doing something right. Insert in question, the array do I get with my query. Perhaps this helps to show what I have on hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your array with a simple foreach:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $data) {
    $output[$data['id']]['id'] = $data['id'];
    $output[$data['id']][$data['label']] = $data['value'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your collaboration. Your code not runs fine in first  because my original question was not well formulated. However, it was your code that elaborate, let me get the desired solution, which shared here on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @KostasMitsarakis in the comments above that this is probably better done on sql level.

However here is the php code you are probably looking for:

```
<?php

$input = [
    [
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'jeff',
        'email' => 'x@mail.com',
        'color' => 'blue',
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'mary',
        'email' => 'y@mail.c',
        'color' => 'pink',
    ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $entry) {
    $element = [];
    foreach($entry as $key=>$val) {
        $element[$key] = $val;
    }
    $output[] = $element;
}


var_dump($output);
```

The ouput of this is:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'id' =>
    int(1)
    'name' =>
    string(4) "jeff"
    'email' =>
    string(10) "x@mail.com"
    'color' =>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'id' =>
    int(2)
    'name' =>
    string(4) "mary"
    'email' =>
    string(8) "y@mail.c"
    'color' =>
    string(4) "pink"
  }
}
```

Comment: Arkascha, your code returns the same array that I have in begins because it is not considering it has more entries with the same id that must be addressed.

Comment: @JeffersonVasconcelos It certainly is _not_ the array you begin with, since its structure is compeltely different: one row (entry) per ID, not many and all properties of a single ID in one row (entry). And I absolutely do not understand why this code should be limited to the number of entries. Instead it is actually implemented such that it works regardless of how many IDs and how many properties per ID you have in the beginning. So: _did you actually look at this answer_? :-)

Comment: @JeffersonVasconcelos Thing is that you apparently revised your question without stating that or saying so. So now it is clear that your entries are actually objects, not arrays, as everyone here expected, which is why my code probably won't work on your data. However that is not because the code returns the same array as you put in (which definitely is _not_ the case), but because you changed the task to be solved. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Arkasha first, thank you for your full attention. After some help, I realized that maybe my question was not very clear, which may be normal to happen to people like me who do not know how to program. Therefore realized change in question. I hope that people can better understand my problem to get help. I'm sorry I made the original question incorrectly.

Comment: @JeffersonVasconcelos All fine, I have absolutely no problem with the fact that a question is changed. In contrary, making a question more precise obviously is a very good thing. All I would want to add here is that you might want to make clear in the question that you changed it, why you did that and what the actual changes were. What I still do not understand at all however is your claim that the code above outputs the same as what has been put in. That clearly is not the case.

Comment: Because the array that you used in your code does not have the same structure of the array that I own. Thus, when applying its code in my case, is returned for me the same array, without the changes that I need. I keep looking for a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but that array has exactly the same structure, except for the fact that after your changes the entries are objects instead of arrays now. This does however not change the structure and the code should e trivial to adapt. Or can you point out a real change in the structure? Son't get me wrong, I am not trying to justify the code or anything, why should I. It is just that I cannot follow your claims, that's all. It would be great if you could explain why, in what detail the structure is different in your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting results as array using [ARRAY_A](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

```
$meta_value = interested_get_meta( 'interested_email' );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
       'SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE post_id 
        IN (    SELECT post_id 
                FROM wp_postmeta 
                WHERE meta_value = "'.$meta_value.'"
            )', ARRAY_A
);

$data = array();
$result = json_decode($results , true); //Return results as array

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['post_id'], $data)) {
        $data[$value['post_id']]['post_id'] = $value['post_id'];
    }
    if ($value['meta_key'] != 'post_id') {
        $data[$value['post_id']][$value['meta_key']] = $value['meta_value'];
    }
}
echo 'id name email color <br />';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['post_id'].' '.$value['name'].' '.$value['email'].' '.$value['color'].'<br />';
}

var_dump($data);
```

**Result (table)**

```
id name email color
1 jeff x@mail.com blue
2 mary y@mail.com pink
```

**Result (var_dump)**

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'post_id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'jeff' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'x@mail.com' (length=10)
      'color' => string 'blue' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'post_id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'mary' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'y@mail.com' (length=10)
      'color' => string 'pink' (length=4)
```

Comment: Kostas, thanks for your help. Your code runs fine when executed as you wrote. But, in my case, the request is returning empty arrays. I'll revise my question entering the code you provided to show my problem.

Comment: Comment out // $data = array(); And then instead of: $results = $wpdb->get_results... WRITE: $data = $wpdb->get_results... because you use $data which in this case is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some hours and coffees, with help of the all people that have wrote here, I found my solution.

```
$meta_value = interested_get_meta('interested_email');

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
           'SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
            FROM wp_postmeta 
            WHERE post_id 
            IN (    SELECT post_id 
                    FROM wp_postmeta 
                    WHERE meta_value = "'.$meta_value.'"
                )', OBJECT
    );

    $data = array();

    if (is_array($results)) {
        foreach($results as $item) {
            $data[$item->post_id]['post_id']           = $item->post_id;
            $data[$item->post_id][$item->meta_key]  = $item->meta_value;
        }
    } 

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $value['post_id'];?><br/>
            <?php echo $value['name'];?><br/>
            <?php echo $value['color'];?><br/>
        </li>
    <?php }
```

Thanks to everyone who helped in any way!